# Outlook does not show folders

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, user-folders

I use Outlook folders for yearly/monthly archiving.   Last month I made October folders for all of my main archive folders in Outlook.

For some reason, NONE of the October folders show up in my Outlook main folders.
I've tried to make new ones, but I get an error message telling me there is already a folder with that name, but the folders I previously made still do not show up.

How do I get them to show up?

Thanks

Comment: This question is lacking details needed for anyone to be able to help you. Please tell us what version you are using, if you are logged into a corporate domain using Exchange, and what your view settings are. And what do you mean by "main folder"? If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Windows 10, Office 2013.   I have a desktop as well as connected to company server.  Whatever view settings are in Outlook, I have no clue.  I have folders listed under "favorites" which are used to store faxes and emails we get.  Folders for the year, then subfolders for months.

Answer (score 0):

You don't create folders in Favorites; it is the other way around. You have to create the folders where you want them, then add to Favorites. Otherwise, they will not be seen in Favorites.

Look at your Folder List and see if the folders are there. Then right click on the folder you want in Favorites and choose `Show in Favorites`. Alternately, you can just drag the folder to Favorites.

***Caution:*** Be sure to use the `Remove from Favorites` rather than delete. If you delete a folder from your Favorites, it will be deleted from Outlook.

Comment: Well, whatever place they are in Outlook, they are not showing up.  And for some reason its only the October folders.  All the November folders show up.

Comment: Is it possible there are some group policies or restrictions being enforced by your domain? Maybe there is a restriction on mailbox size and your storage procedure is exceeding it. Check with your IT department.